# Find key in Javascript object and get values for each one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this code:

```
$.post(Routing.generate('vincularFabricanteModeloMarca'), {
    fabricantesMarcaModelo: fabricantesMarcaModelo.serializeArray(),
    paresMarcaModelo: paresMarcaModelo.serializeArray()
}, 'json').done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if (data.success) {
        console.log(data.ent);

        $.each(data.ent, function (k, v) {
            var countries = '';
            var maker = '';

            var makerId = null;
            console.log(v.paisesFabricanteModeloMarca);

            $.each(v.paisesFabricanteModeloMarca, function (l, w) {
                $.each(w, function (x, z) {
                    countries += (countries == '' ? '' : ', ') + z.nombrepais;
                    maker = z.nombrefabricantedistribuidor;
                    makerId = z.idfabricantedistribuidor;
                });

                var btn = '<button data-rel-id="' + makerId + '" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-fabricante"><i class="fa fa-close fx"></i> ' + maker + ' (' + countries + ')</button>';
                $('td[data-modelomarcaproductofabricantes="' + v.idModeloMarca + '"]').append(btn);
            });
        });
    }
}).fail(function () { });
```

How do I get the `key` value on this Javascript object on this result set in order to find the right `td` on this line:

```
$('td[data-modelomarcaproductofabricantes="' + (here) + '"]').append(btn);
```

*(here)* should be the key for each loop, how? See the pictures below for a test result set, any advice?

**console.log(data.ent)**

[image: this is what console.log(data.ent) returns]

**This is the server side response as a JSON**

[image]

Comment: @noob didn't try but has no sense to me at all since `idModeloMarca` is the key of each array not viceversa

Comment: looking at your code and JSON, I feel like you are missing a loop, it structure seems to be Array-->Object-->Object-->Array, and your loop is like Array-->Object-->Array, check if this works, ``` $.each(Object.keys(v), function(k1,v1){ console.log(v[v1].paisesFabricanteModeloMarca)});```

Comment: Can you place a answer instead of code here? Is a bit unreadable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after **@mido22** suggestion I rewrite my own code and get this:

```
$.each(data.ent, function (k, v) {
    var countries = '',
        maker = '',
        makerId = null;

    $.each(v, function (l, w) {
        $.each(w.paisesFabricanteModeloMarca, function (i, j) {
            countries += (countries == '' ? '' : ', ') + j.nombrepais;
            maker = j.nombrefabricantedistribuidor;
            makerId = j.idfabricantedistribuidor;
        });

        var btn = '<button data-rel-id="' + makerId + '" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-fabricante"><i class="fa fa-close fx"></i> ' + maker + ' (' + countries + ')</button>';
        $('td[data-modelomarcaproductofabricantes="' + l + '"]').append(btn);
    });
});
```

Fully functional and *apparently* works for me! Hope this help others. Happy codding!!

Answer (score 1):

looking at your code and JSON, I feel like you are missing a loop,

The JSON structure seems to be Array-->Object-->Object-->Array,
 and your loop is like Array-->Object-->Array,

check if this works,

```
$.each(Object.keys(v), function(k1,v1){  
    console.log(v[v1].paisesFabricanteModeloMarca);
});
```

Comment: I'm lost, could you use the exact values from the function? What `Object` refers to on your code? The first Object? The second one?

Comment: from what i am seeing, ent -->Array of Objects,(level1)
each Object has a key "14": Object (level2)
 Object with key "paisesFabricanteModeloMarca": Array( level3)